# Randomly registered users

Tags: app-store, testflight

I am distributing my apps via the App Store and testing before release with TestFlight. Today I noticed a user registered with the TestFlight version. So I checked another user and I saw an old version of my app used to register. All those users were registered with Apple sign-in.

Does Apple randomly register bot users to make automation tests? Normally Google does this when I send for approval. Immediately 3 users register with Google account and use Google Sign in.

So if this is the case how can I eliminate those bot users from real ones? If it is not how can be possible a user can install the from the TestFlight? (public link is disabled, only test users can install)